# CDC Not working after 24 hours

Tags: heroku, change-data-capture

Was doing some testing with Change Data Capture and Heroku and now I am not receiving any events. This is against a brand new Developer Edition (DE) org. However, if I switch my connection to another org it works. What limit could I be hitting? Not seeing anything stick out in the `/limits` API in Workbench.

Answer (score 2):

`Limits` rest api does not give accurate data (We faced this issue in prod and salesforce support team reverted with this comment). Your handshake might be failing.

Try with `workbench` to subscribe to Streaming push topic, for developer edition  there is a concurrent user [limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/limits.htm) (Client subscription) of 20.

Just click `Streaming push topics` from workbench , if you see error there then you will get to know what limit did you hit.

[image]

This is the limit you might be hitting.